# Adding data to MySQL after a foreign key is defined

Tags: mysql

I've got a general question about databases. I'm using a MySQL db, and have found that I can't add values to a table after I define a foreign key. Could someone comment on what may be the reason for this? I made a simple table 'test1', and want to cascade delete and update the table when values in a column3 are identical with a value in the primary column. I can add the foreign key when the table is empty of data, but when I try to add data after setting the foreign key, it won't allow it. The referenced column isn't unique. Suggestions are welcome. Hope I've explained my situation well enough.

Comment: What do you mean "it won't allow it"?  What specifically are you attempting and what specifically is the result?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read this http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/271056/ and please consider making an [edit] to your question.

Comment: does it throw the error as in "can't update/ delete as a child table.." Thats because a column in the foreign table refers to another column in the primary table. So, you can't change values as it may affect the other. If you delete the values which refers the primary, you can make changes that dont affect the primary.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response. I put together a forum website, and what I'm trying to do is cascade delete/update rows that reference the primary key row; for instance, if the topic is in the primary key as #32, all rows with the #32 in the referenced cell will be deleted or updated. I made a simple test table, and made sure that the column types were the same, but when I try to add data to the table after I set the foreign key, I get an error #1452, can't add or update a child row...foreign key constraint fails. That's generally what I'm trying to accomplish, and the error I'm getting.

Comment: Hey folks, thanks for your input. Alan, your response zeroed me in on what the problem is. I found that if I referenced the primary key, the value in the reference cell had to contain one of the primary values. Like, I couldn't have a value of '5', if there wasn't a value of '5' somewhere in the primary key. Learning on my end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

thanks for your input. Alan, your response zeroed me in on what the problem is. I found that if I referenced the primary key, the value in the reference cell had to contain one of the primary values. Like, I couldn't have a value of '5', if there wasn't a value of '5' somewhere in the primary key. Learning on my end!